# Dharma and adharma sides of the Kurukshetra war

Tags: mahabharata

In the Kurukshetra war, the Pandava side represented Dharma, and the Kaurava side adharma.Then, why numerous warriors in the Pandavas' side also died in the battle?

Comment: 10 wars were happened between Gods and Demons and all those daityas, Rakshasa who were killed by Devas were born as humans and Earth was filled with evil and chaos. Then lord Vishnu descended to Earth as Krishna and his attendants in vaikunta as Yadavas and Devas as other allies. So, killing must happen to relieve the earth and Devas went to their original abodes and these Demons too went to heaven after war and thus Earth was relieved of burden and this was main reason for krishna Avatar.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Nice explanation  friend

Comment: Once Death doesnt define he is  for dharma or adharma. what cause the person died that determines the dharma.. Kaurava side people died and went hell as well but those who died on Pandavas never went to hell.

Answer (score 2):

Mahabharata was a war between dharma and adharma. This is clear from what happened after the death of the Pandavas and Kauravas.

Yudhishthira was shocked to see Duryodhana in heaven while his brothers were in hell. This peculiar phenomena was explained by Indra.

> Then Sakra, the lord of the deities, endued with blazing prosperity,
> addressed Yudhishthira and comforting him, said, "O Yudhishthira of
> mighty arms, come, come, O Chief of men. These illusions have ended, O
> puissant one. Success has been attained by thee, O mighty-armed one,
> and eternal regions (of felicity) have become thine. Hell, O son,
> should without doubt, be beheld by every king. Of both good and bad
> there is abundance, O chief of men. **He enjoys the fruits of his good
> acts must afterwards endure hell. He, on the other hand, who first
> endures Hell, must afterwards enjoy Heaven, He whose sinful acts are
> many, enjoy heaven first.**..."

**Mahabharata, Swargarohanika Parva, Section III**

Duryodhana's sins were greater than his good deeds while the Pandavas had done more good deeds than bad ones. **Of course neither side was perfect but on balance Pandavas were on the side of dharma while the Kauravas were on the side of adharma.**

Fighting for Dharma is not the only factor governing the lives of the warriors in a war. Each of these warriors also have their own karmic history.

> ...As it does and as it acts, so it becomes: **The doer of good becomes
> good, and the doer of evil becomes evil; it becomes virtuous through a
> virtuous act and vicious through a vicious act.** Others, however, say
> that the self is identified with desire alone. It resolves as it
> desires; it does the work that it resolves; and it attains the results
> of the work it does.

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad, 4.4.5

Warriors fighting for dharma are earning merit. However, one cannot forget the past karmas of these warriors. So warriors who died did not have enough karmic merit to survive the war.

Comment: Krishna himself admitted they won the war by Adharma.  They shattered the enemy king's thighs and left him alive on the spot to the mercy of wild animals.  The celestials showered flowers on Duryodhana on his death-bed when he read Krishna the laundry-list of treacheries committed by him.@pradipgangopadhyay  Actually neither side was dharmic.

Answer (score 1):

Mahabharat was not a war of Dharma and Adharma.

> I pray to thee, **O bull of the Kshatriya race, let not the Kshatriyas, old in learning and old in years, perish miserably,** O Janardana, for thy sake. Oh, let this swelling host of Kshatriyas perish by means of weapons on that most sacred of all spots in the three worlds, viz.
>
> https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05141.htm

Read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38785/19001) for more information.

Comment: 'Mahabharat was not a war of Dharma and Adharma' - the very first chapter divides the two sides on that basis. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nseyQ.png).

Comment: @sv. Please tell me where is Dharma and Adharma is written in the passage.

Comment: Compare "Yudhishthira is a great tree created out of **righteousness**..." with the Sanskrit verse from [here](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01001.htm): "yudhiṣṭhiro **dharmamayo** mahādrumaḥ...". If one side is portrayed as founded in dharma that implies the other side is following adharma.

Comment: @sv. **. If one side is portrayed as founded in dharma that implies the other side is following adharma.** This thing is based on your own thinking. Yes, Yudhishthira was righteous but it doesn't means that Kurukshetra war was a war of righteousness and unrighteousness. Read in the previous shlokas, Vedvyas called Duryodhana, a tree of *passion*(मन्यु=passion). Could you cite a single verse where Vedvyas called Duryodhana an Adharmi?

Comment: "Could you cite a single verse where Vedavyasa called Duryodhana an Adharmi?" - If I do, will you delete this answer?

Comment: @sv. **If I do, will you delete this answer? ** Each and every person had done some adharmas in their life. Please site a verse which clearly says that Duryodhana was in side of Adharma. By the way, there are some verses where Yudhishthira seems to be an Adharmi. After death, Duryodhana directly got heaven while Yudhishthira was first sent to hell.

Comment: Interesting, you went from "a single verse where Vedavyasa called Duryodhana an Adharmi?" to "a verse which clearly says that Duryodhana was in side of Adharma" -- so whatever verse I cite you can then say "mistranslation", "taken out of context", etc. Excellent.

Comment: Check this post: [Did Kauravas admit their Adharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8902/did-kauravas-admit-their-adharma). Gandhari [speaking about](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02074.htm) her own son: "Therefore, at my word, O king, abandon this wretch of our race."

Comment: @sv. What nonsense is this? I was asking for the words of Vedvyas not Gandhari. Even So called Dharmaraj admitted that:-I caused also my eldest brother Karna to be slain, that terrible warrior who never retreated from battle. **Who is there more sinful than I**? https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a027.htm?fbclid=IwAR1TBVrec3bfVCesc-9MrVgx0_vO8B5h45O-JZpfVSH_z6FAMIkun2-7XMw

Comment: Does Gandhari know her son better or Vyasa? Even assuming the whole Mahabharata is a fictional story and Vyasa its author, it was Vyasa who made Gandhari say those words.

Comment: @sv. If this thing is true, then you should accept that Duryodhana was a good person because Gandhari said that Duryodhana was high souled:https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVgpl.png

Comment: @sv. Gandhari criticizing Duryodhana could be because of grief but Sage Narada called Duryodhana a high souled person :-https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvHMA.png

Comment: "Gandhari criticizing Duryodhana could be because of grief" - as I expected we are in the "words taken out of context" territory now. Can you find Kunti saying something like "O king, abandon this wretch of our race" about Yudhishthira or any of the Pandavas? Re: Narada's statements, I wouldn't take them seriously. If everyone who dies in battlefield goes to swarga then the concept of dharma vs. adharma can be put in a trashcan.

Comment: @sv. Yudhishthira confessed that he was asinful person as I said in previous comment. Who could know Yudhishthira better than himself. His wife called him a gambler:-*'O son of the Suta race, go, and ask that **gambler** present in the assembly, whom he hath lost first, himself, or me.*https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02066.htm?fbclid=IwAR3vcWatGF7wLwHIlkq6YrsRylNv5JBdiBwgy3OJ_IPmuvOYq1juxFs5kTY. His own brother Arjuna criticized him.https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08070.htm?fbclid=IwAR0TsmncRC0wBiwIswELvzsp7lR8T3f0hDiW4xwvxiT3h92lIrDHoO48_70

Comment: @sv. These types of opinions are not valid. Same Gandhari called Duryodhana a follower of truth. That's why I was asking for the opinion of Vyasa or any high souled god like Lord Krishna or someone else. Sage Narada accepted that Duryodhana followed Dharma in his whole life. Everyone who dies in battle goes to heaven but Narada said that he got heaven because he followed Dharma. He didn't killed warriors unfairly.Can you tell me that because of which sin you are calling Duryodhana a sinner?