# Are the Kauravas considered Sinners while the Pandavas not?

Tags: pandavas, kauravas, pandu

Are the Sinners found in both sides (Kauravas and Pandavas) or the Kauravas alone were antidharma?

I mean: why when the Pandavas king Yudhishthira ascended to heaven he saw Kauravas smiling and in a good state while his near relatives in a bad situation and suffering?. If this was an illusion, then where it is mentioned in the Epic?.

What about marriage of one woman by the Five brothers, 
a Common wife, isn't  this a Sin, even we may consider it as a Crime?.

What about  a Hundred brothers and one sister of the same bulk? Isn't this a good thing?

Comment: Pandavas followed the Dharma, however in that process the committed sins of killing their relatives, elders and Gurus etc.

Comment: "his near relatives in a bad situation and suffering"- this was just illusion.. Yudhishthir's near relatives were not suffering but Yudhishthir thought so due to illusion...

Comment: "_What about a Hundred brothers and one sister of the same bulk? Isn't this a good thing?_" -- what do you mean by this? What is good or bad in this? "_What about the inability of their father Pandu to get Sons?_" - how is this a sin?

Comment: @sv. I mean one hundred brothers from one origin and one sister, should be Dear to them all. They also have no sexual misbehaviour. On the other hand the Pandavas have sexual crime, a common wife.

Comment: Are you talking about the birth of Pandavas? That they were not legitimate children of Pandu and Kunti? So a sin? I think you should edit and make your question title/body simple: Did the Pandavas commit any sins? And list a few things you think might be sins without comparing with the actions/sins of Kauravas. Also, replace 'pancharatra' tag with 'pandavas'.

Comment: @sv. Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: I find the question all over the place and still being edited. Will not be surprised if it ends up being a duplicate of an existing question

Answer (score 2):

Biggest misconception is that Mahabharata was fought for establishing Dharma. Mahabharat was a war of *Adharma vs Adharma*. Even Lord Krishna [accepted](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09061.htm) this thing.

> If I had not adopted such deceitful ways in battle, victory would never have been yours, nor kingdom, nor wealth!

Lord Krishna talks about wealth and kingdom. Where is Dharma? Mahabharat was not fought for the Dharma establishment. It was for liberation of kshatriyas. Karna [said](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05141.htm) to Krishna.

> I pray to thee, O bull of the Kshatriya race, **let not the Kshatriyas, old in learning and old in years, perish miserably,** O Janardana, for thy sake. Oh, **let this swelling host of Kshatriyas perish by means of weapons on that most sacred of all spots in the three worlds, viz.**

So Krishna helped pandavas in Mahabharat for liberation of kshatriyas not for establishment of Dharma. Krishna helped weaker side so stronger kshatriyas could be killed. That's why no pandava was killed in the war but all three disciples of Parshurama, all great kuru warriors perished. Due to this war, Gandhari cursed Krishna and Yadava clan was also destroyed. So Mahabharat was fought for Liberation of kshatriyas. You will surprised to know that it was Karna not Arjuna who was born for helping Krishna [in](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a002.htm)the war.

> O mighty-armed one, as it befell in former days. How all the Kshatriyas, cleansed by weapons should attain to regions of bliss, was the question. For this, a child was conceived by Kunti in her maidenhood, capable of provoking a general war.

So Karna was born to help Lord Krishna in liberation of kshatriyas.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken

Comment: @ThePreserver thnx. I will fix the problem. Give me time